# How to modify Django's Manager QuerySet create() method?

Tags: django

I have two models, `Invoice` and `InvoiceItems`, which have a one-to-many relationship.

Throughout the code base we're creating `InvoiceItems` for a given `Invoice` using the `Manager` object as:

```
invoice.invoice_items.create(...)
```

The thing is, now we have a validation that has to take place before trying to create an `InvoiceItem`, and going through the codebase, refactoring all the creation pieces would be a headache.

I wonder if there's a way to override the create method itself or should we go for the model's `save()`?

Answer (score 0):

To modify a Manager's method you need to create your own. Given the following case:

```
# models
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # ... fields
    objects = MyManager()

class MyManager(models.Manager):

    def create(self):
        # write your own code here
        pass
```

Do not worry about the others methods (`filter`, `delete`, etc.) all of them will work as usual.

You can find more about custom managers [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/#set-use-for-related-fields-when-you-define-the-class)